# Bus bunching simulation code

Tags: trees, linked-list

I'm having a peculiar issue to solve. What I am supposed to implement is a bus transit simulation in which there are passengers coming at some random generated time intervals and are added into a queue and they wait for the bus to arrive at bus stops and bus stops there and they board the bus until the queue is empty. It is assumed that every passenger takes exact same time to board the bus. As the queue is empty, the bus moves towards the next bus stop for the same thing. There are several buses and several bus stops. Lets say if a person queue at some bus stop is bigger than the person queue at another bus stop, the bus will take more time to fill at that stop and because of that the successive bus stop will have a larger queue too and again the bus had to wait there for a longer time. This issue will be continued until the buses bunch as a single whole and move just behind each other. Bus are not allowed to cross each other.

I need to implement this in any language. I think python would be fine for this job. Positively thinking to go with Python.

I have tried to break down this problem into parts. So before starting stops are equidistant from each other and person queue is empty. Then the buses start moving and person queue starts increasing and as soon as a bus reach a person queue at a particular bus stop, person queue will decrement to zero and bus will move to the next bus stop. A thing to notice here is person queue is truncated in a manner that each dequeue operation is carried out in a specific amount of time. So if 5 persons are to be removed from the queue, they will take 3 seconds * 5 = 15 seconds for the entire dequeue or truncation of a person queue. The bus on reaching the next bus stop will check whether person queue is empty or not and if not, then it will dequeue until truncated and move ahead. This implementation, when extended for 5 buses and 15 bus stops will lead to bus bunching at some point of time since buses cannot cross each other.

Kindly provide me some ideas to make it as simple as possible because this is something that I need to demonstrate but not use anywhere as an actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you need to represent individual riders at all, except as numeric aggregates.  Don’t let the fact that, in (British) English, people line up in queues for the bus mislead you about which data structure to use!

What I would suggest is:

A parameterized path representing the bus route, with the bus stops as points along the route.  (If your demonstration is graphical, these can be knots, and you will have a very straightforward translation to a b-spline.)

The position of each bus along the route, represented as a periodic *t* value along the path.

A number of people on each bus.  You might represent a fixed percentage getting off at each stop, so the number of riders exponentially decays.

A number of people waiting at each stop.  If the stops have a certain population of potential riders and a certain chance that any of them will show up per minute, this could be modeled by a hypergeometric random variable.  What’s important for the demonstration, though, is that the number of people at each stop grow the longer it takes the next bus to arrive (preferably at an asymptotic rate).  You could just roll the dice each minute, add the successes, and get the same result.